# What does decimals/fungible token normalization mean? I need help with mitigating precision loss

Tags: solidity, foundry, decimals

What is the code to convert them to correct decimals without precision loss?Does it mean that you should make all the token decimals to a certain standard of the protocol? Let say 18?

If Token A is 16 & Token B is 21 decimals places should you convert both to 18?

```
// (18, tokens decimals, amount)
convertDecimals(NORMALIZED_DECIMALS_TO_18, decimals, amount);
```

Now the question is how do you convert if this is the following scenario:

1. Token A amount of tokens is 1e16.
2. Token A amount of tokens is 1e18.
3. Token A amount of tokens is 1e21.
4. Token B amount of tokens is 1e16.
5. Token B amount of tokens is 1e18.
6. Token B amount of tokens is 1e21.

Answer (score 0):

Just add or subtract zeros to the Bignumbers to make equivalences. If Token A is 16 & Token B is 21, you have to add 5 zeros to Token A, or remove 5 zeros from Token B.

I understand that they are equivalent, i.e. A = B.

If you want to pass the tokens to `ether weis` you have to remove 3 from B or add 2 to A.

You can see that in [ether converter](https://eth-converter.com/)

```
    function addDecimals(uint _amount, uint _decimals) pure external returns  (uint)
    {
        return _amount *  (10 **_decimals);
    }

       function subsDecimals(uint _amount, uint _decimals) pure external returns  (uint)
    {
        return _amount /  (10 **_decimals);
    }
```